# Joining two tables based upon the highest COUNT(*) from table2?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Okay, so I have two tables that I need to link together with a `JOIN` query. There is a table called likes and a table called users. The users table looks something like this

```
id         name
-----      ------
1          Mark
2          Mike
3          Paul
4          Dave
5          Chris
6          John
```

The likes table looks like this.

```
user_one   user_two  match_id
-----      ------    --------
1          2           abc
2          1
1          3           acc
3          1           abb
1          5           aee
5          1
```

The expected result should be

```
id         name
-----      ------
1          Mark
```

The two tables should only be linked on the rows in the likes table where the users_one column is set to the value that is most commonly found in that column. In this case, the user with the `id` of `1` is in the likes table with the `user_one` column 3 times where the `match_id` isn't empty.

I've thought it out to be written something like this

```
SELECT users.*, likes.COUNT(*) AS count
FROM users
JOIN likes
ON users.id = likes.user_one
WHERE likes.match_id != ''
```

But, I know this isn't correct. Is there a way to link two tables with a JOIN only on the most common rows in one of the tables?

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: I need to know what the query should be

Comment: You never explain in your question what match_id is and how it should fit into the query.

Comment: But it is not clear what you need. Why you do not want 3  Paul.

Comment: Also, your desired result does not correspond with the query you think should work. And I really don't understand whether the query should return just one row, with the user with the most likes or multiple rows with every user and the corresponding most likes, involving a join? Could you try to just describe the result in one simple sentence?

Comment: Or better a complete example with a description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would Grouping work for what you need... ?

```
  SELECT users.id, users.name, count(*) AS count
    FROM users
    JOIN likes
    ON users.id = likes.user_one
    WHERE likes.match_id != '' 
    group by users.id, users.name
```

should give you something like

```
1   Mark   3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select *
from users
where id in (
    select id
    from likes
    group by id
    order by count(*) desc, id
    limit 1
)
```

The subquery returns the `id` of the row with the most appearances in the *likes* table (`group by id` and `order by count(*) desc`).  I've added `id` to the `order by` to give predictable results in case there are multiple with the same number of appearances.  This is used to join to the *users* table to give the resultset required.

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like this, if I understood the question

```
select top 1 user_one, name
from likes 
inner join users ON users.id = likes.user_one
where match_id != ''
group by user_one
order by count(*) Desc
```

Comment: `top 1` is sql-server syntax and do not work on mysql.

Comment: Ok, sorry. But the meaning doesn't change.

Comment: OP asking for a solution in mysql not the meaning!

Comment: Come on, the question was about the logic of the query. Syntax is a detail.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
select u.id, u.name, count(*)
from users u
inner join likes l
on l.id = l.user_one and l.match_id != ''
group by u.id, u.name
order by count(*) desc
limit 1
```

The `limit 1`, combined with sorting by the # of likes in descending order will result in getting one user - the one with the most matched likes.